# Is there a way to check if an element has mouse hovered?

Tags: angular

Is there a way to check if an element has mouse hovered? So that I can write expressions like `isHovered ? a : b`

For the moment, I have to rely on the event: `(mouseenter)="isStarHover=true" (mouseleave)="isStarHover=false"`

Answer (score 2):

I use @HostListener within my components. If I need to handle specific element, then the same solution from question with directives (mouseenter)/(mouseleave) is used.

```
 @HostListener('mouseenter')
  public mouseenterListener(): void {
    this.hover = true;
  }

  @HostListener('mouseleave')
  public mouseleaveListener(): void {
    this.hover = false;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try using `is()` and check for the selector `:hover`.
`var isHovered = $('#elem').is(":hover"); // returns true or false`

Comment: You should never use jQuery like this in Angular app, so this answer is not very good.

Comment: @dfsq please suggest better solution

Comment: @dfsq obtain `ElementRef` in constructor: `constructor(private readonly el: ElementRef) {}`, then test CSS selector: `(this.el.nativeElement as HTMLElement).matches(':hover')` .